# Configuring local db location in Entity Framework

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, connection-string

I am trying to configure a different location for my local db.

I read an [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us//library/cc716756.aspx) on configuring connection strings and it suggests I can replace |DataDirectory| in the web config with ~/MyDirectory where ~ is the web app root. So I have input the connection string as:

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="Context" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=Context-20130829161219;Integrated Security=SSPI;AttachDBFilename=~/MyDirectory/Context-20130829161219.mdf"
  providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Unfortunately, when I run the app it doesn't seem to create the db at all. I can imagine it's only something very small that I am doing wrong but I would appreciate if someone can point me in the right direction.

Many Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Lets try with below string it will help you

```
<add name="Context" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.Datacontext.csdl|res://*/Models.Datacontext.ssdl|res://*/Models.Datacontext.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=(LocalDb)\SQLInstance;initial catalog=Context-20130829161219;persist security info=True;user id=sa;password=Yourpassword;multipleactiveresultsets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

or replace your Source=(LocalDb)\SQLInstance;initial with **Source=.\SQLInstance;initial**

Answer (score 1):

Try running the `Update-Database` cmdlet from the package manager console - you should at least see some output indicating why it doesn't work.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I get the following error: A file activation error occurred. The physical file name '~/MyDirectory/Context-20130829161220.mdf' may be incorrect. Diagnose and correct additional errors, and retry the operation.

Comment: Yes, when replacing ~/MyDirectory/ with |DataDirectory| everything works fine